# Topologial Sort in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, graph

I am trying to self study algorithms and this is my attempt at topological sort using Tarjan's version of DFS. It runs correctly for the graph I included. Can someone tell me if this is correct and if/what optimizations I can make?

```
graph = {
'A':['C'],
'B': ['C', 'D'],
'C': ['E'],
'D': ['F'],
'E': ['F'],
'F': ['G'],
'G': [],
}

def topological_sort(graph):
    visited, stack = set(), []

    for vertex in graph:
        handle_vertex(graph, vertex, visited, stack) 

    print(stack)

def handle_vertex(graph, vertex, visited, stack):
    if vertex not in visited:
        visited.add(vertex)

    for neighbors in graph[vertex]:
        if neighbors not in visited:
            handle_vertex(graph, neighbors, visited, stack)

    if vertex not in stack:
       stack.insert(0, vertex)
    return stack

print(topological_sort(graph))
```

Comment: Do you only have one test case? Does the code work correctly for other test cases?

Comment: @Phrancis it also works for the test case: graph2={
    0 : [],
    1: [],
    2: [3],
    3: [1],
    4: [0, 1],
    5: [2, 0]
}

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but can you please explain what's the output you expect for the graph in the code ? More, could you please add more context to what your code does ? Having some recursion going on there doesn't help :). **PS:** for example, when I'm testing you're first graph, I receive different outputs at every run, so I suspect your code as being broken.

Comment: @Dex'ter A topological sort returns things in order, where given an edge U->V in a graph, U always comes before V.

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't get the point of returning the `stack` from the `handle_vertex` function. The return value is never used (and the `stack` which is passed as an argument is modified in place).
2. The `topological_sort` functions prints the `stack`, doesn't return anything and then it's returned value is printed: `print(topological_sort(graph))`. There're two reasonable options here:

   - not printing the returned value of the `topological_sort` and just calling it instead
   - Returning the `stack` from it instead of printing it inside the function.
3. The `neighbors` name here: `for neighbors in graph[vertex]` is misleading. This variable represent just one neighbor at a time. I don't see why would you make it plural.